# Undocumented value in DfsrIdRecordInfo class

Tags: wmi, dfs-r

According to MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540013(v=vs.85).aspx) these are the only possible values of the "flags" attribute of the DfsrIdRecordInfo wmi class:

> Data type: uint8 Access type: Read-only
>
> A combination of flags for present, authoritative, and file type
>   flags.
>
> PRESENT_FLAG 0x1 The resource is not a tombstone; it is available on
>   the computer.
>
> NAME_CONFLICT_FLAG 0x2 The tombstone was generated because of a name
>   conflict. This flag is meaningful only for tombstones.
>
> UID_VISIBLE_FLAG 0x4 The ID record has already been sent out to other
>   partners; therefore, other partners are aware of this resource.
>
> JOURNAL_WRAP_FLAG 0x10 The volume has had a journal wrap and the
>   resource has not been checked to determine if there is any change by
>   the journal wrap recovery process.
>
> PENDING_TOMBSTONE_FLAG 0x20 The ID record is in the process of being
>   tombstoned (or deleted.)

When I check one of my files it reports a value of "5" for its flags attribute. What the heck does a value of "5" mean?

```
__GENUS              : 2
__CLASS              : DfsrIdRecordInfo
__SUPERCLASS         : 
__DYNASTY            : DfsrIdRecordInfo
__RELPATH            : DfsrIdRecordInfo.Uid="{6A33C970-929A-4052-ACB5-92520F3B0E7C}-v3794"
__PROPERTY_COUNT     : 17
__DERIVATION         : {}
__SERVER             : MYSERVER
__NAMESPACE          : root\microsoftdfs
__PATH               : \\MYSERVER\root\microsoftdfs:DfsrIdRecordInfo.Uid="{6A33C970-929A-4052-ACB5-92520F3B0E7C}-v3794"
Attributes           : 32
Clock                : 20130322134516.934807-000
CreateTime           : 20130322134514.017682-000
Fence                : 3
Fid                  : 1970324837048435
FileHash             : 6ab5e41820f1c6d0 91fd3ef981e4d98f
FileName             : test.txt
****Flags                : 5*****
FullPathName         : C:\Myfolder\test.txt
GVsn                 : {6A33C970-929A-4052-ACB5-92520F3B0E7C}-v3795
Index                : 1536
ParentUid            : {D1AC58C9-B5DB-4595-8D7A-BF271866B18D}-v1
ReplicatedFolderGuid : D1AC58C9-B5DB-4595-8D7A-BF271866B18D
Uid                  : {6A33C970-929A-4052-ACB5-92520F3B0E7C}-v3794
UpdateTime           : 20130322141644.440697-000
Usn                  : 303139856
Volume               : \\.\C:
PSComputerName       : MYSERVER
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's documented quite clearly, emphasis mine:

> A **combination of flags** [note the plural] for present, authoritative, and file type flags.

Using your values:

```
PRESENT_FLAG     0x1
UID_VISIBLE_FLAG 0x4 +
--------------------
Flag Combination 0x5
```

This indicates both `PRESENT_FLAG` and `UID_VISIBLE_FLAG` are set.

Comment: Whoa, must not have had enough coffee today. Sorry for an unnecessary thread!

Comment: @user1028270 Not a problem. Sometimes it takes upwards of two eyes to parse the documentation correctly.  I've had the same issue. Glad you actually brought the docs though, that's more than some. :)